# Remove hash keys having values less than 1000

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash like this:

```
my_hash = {"Ace"=>1678.987, "Token"=>389, "Coin"=>17.765,
           "Zowo"=>2020, "Zerlam"=>42, "Ksoz"=>26366.5}
```

and want to create a new hash comprised of keys-value pairs of `my_hash` having values less than `1000`:

```
{"Token"=>389, "Coin"=>17.765, "Zerlam"=>42}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: When asking we need to see your effort toward solving the problem. You gave us an invalid hash definition and a required result in another invalid hash definition but nothing show us what you'd tried, which means we'd have to write a tutorial to explain everything. "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" are important reading. Notice, it took you 13 minutes to find the solution which implies you didn't try hard enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found !

```
new_hash = my_hash.delete_if {|k, v| v > 1000}
```

Comment: The OP wants to create a new hash. This modifies `my_hash` in place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Hash#reject](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Hash/reject) method. Assuming that all values can be compared to 1000 (ie they are not strings nor nils):

`new_hash = my_hash.reject{|key, value| value >= 1000}`

Comment: You want `value >= 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```rb
new_hash = my_hash.select {|_, value| value < 1000 }
```